# How can I tell how old my fairy castle cactus is?

Tags: cactus

this is my new fairy castle cactus also referred to as a green finger cactus(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpBSg.jpg)

Comment: Try to ask in the seller, sometimes they know.

Comment: I bought it from Walmart and they said they have no idea...

Answer (score 1):

It's virtually impossible to get an exact age. From the way these look they may be rooted cuttings which further obscures things.

Grown from seed, I would expect a plant like this to take 2-5 years depending on conditions.